# How to open Link from Facebook canvas game?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-canvas

How can I set up link to open in a new tab from Facebook canvas app?

I made a game created script, link opens from unity engine but not in canvas app. Is there any other api to click external link from canvas?

I used this script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class url : MonoBehaviour {
    public string links = "Paste your links here...";
    void OnClick()  {
        Debug.Log ("mouseclick");
        Application.OpenURL(links);
    }
}
```

Here are my links which are loading but not opening in game:

> https://apps.facebook.com/icecreammania/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have more control if you do it from the browsers javascript.

Define a function on your canvas page that does this and call it from unity using [Application.ExternalCall](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebPlayerandbrowsercommunication.html).

Comment: Yeah it should work. Is it right code i writtern.


`Application.ExternalCall ("openNewURL");    
type="text/javascript">    
function openNewURL()    
{  
window.open('http://someURL.com', 'open_window')  
}`

Comment: @NabeelSaleem: You don't want the `'open_window'` part - it opens a new window/tab and names id 'open_window'. Either use the special values of `'_top'` or  `'_parent'` or use `location.href="http://someURL.com"` instead of `window.open`.